# TikZ images won't compile externally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex, luatex, tikz-external

I have a number of large plots which exhaust memory when I try to compile them with `xelatex`, so I am using `lualatex` instead, which is able to compile them without major difficulty.

However, I am unable to get my documents to compile externally. I normally use [Texmaker](http://xm1math.net/texmaker/index_fr.html) as my editor and build with `xelatex`, but the problems with externalization happen also when I run `pdflatex --shell-escape` or `xelatex -shell-escape` from the command line.

If I run `pdflatex --shell-escape <filename>.tex`, pdflatex runs with \write18 enabled:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./external.tex
```

...but terminates with this error:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex --shell-escape -halt-
on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "external-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalr
ealjob{external}\input{external}"' ========
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013052800 (rev 4627) 
 \write18 enabled.
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
Syntax Warning: PDF file is damaged - attempting to reconstruct xref table...
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./external-figure0.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image 
failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I run `xelatex --shell-escape <filename>.tex`, xelatex also runs with \write18 enabled:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013) (format=xelatex 2013.9.6)  18 SEP 2013 18:14
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**external.tex
(./external.tex
```

... but in this case, lualatex stops with this error:

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'lualatex --shell-escape -halt-
on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "external-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalr
ealjob{external}\input{external}"' ========
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013052800 (rev 4627) 
 \write18 enabled.
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
! Unable to load picture or PDF file 'external-figure0.pdf'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.34 \end{tikzpicture}

?
```

and waits for input.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex --shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
height=9cm,
width=9cm,
grid=major,
]
\addplot {-x^5 - 242};
\addlegendentry{model}
\addplot coordinates {
(-4.77778,2027.60977)
(-3.55556,347.84069)
(-2.33333,22.58953)
(-1.11111,-493.50066)
(0.11111,46.66082)
(1.33333,-205.56286)
(2.55556,-341.40638)
(3.77778,-1169.24780)
(5.00000,-3269.56775)
};
\addlegendentry{estimate}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using Tex Live 2013. I also had this problem in Tex Live 2012. It's not clear to me what's wrong here.

Comment: I do find the idea to combine standalone + externalize a bit odd and it is imho not really a surprise that they thread on the other toes. Use either the article class or only standalone.

Answer (score 4):

Standalone creates an encapsulated PDF image, which can be treated like any other image.
Lose the externalize, create a PDF file named (for example) tikz.pdf and run

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{tikz.pdf}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

or some variant thereof.

Comment: I have to externalize because the images require too much memory. I have heard from more than a few people that standalone and externalize don't play nicely together. I also don't want to be building images manually. I will have to do these without standalone and build separate wrappers to build the just the graphics for review purposes.

Comment: Then just lose the externalize for standalone.  That's what I did.

Answer (score 2):

I suffered the very same problem in conjunction with the package pgfplots - which uses Tikz to draw pretty scientific plots and also makes use of its externalization library.

I store all externalized files in a subfolder *pgfplotsfigures* using the setting:

```
\tikzexternalize[prefix=pgfplotsfigures/]
```

Removing all files in said folder also removed the error and the tex-file could be properly compiled without stumbling over unreadable xref dicts.